# is there any way to split a number into an array of ranges?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a variable `$v` that is a number

Now I need to split this `$v` into multiple chuncks of ranges, for example:
when `$v` is 44, it should be spliced into `[0..10]`, `[11..20]`, `[21..30]`, `[31..40]` and `[41..44]`.

I know we can split string but in this case it's a number, any idea?

Comment: How do you split a string in a similar way ?

Comment: unclear, show examples

Comment: "[0..10], [11..20], [21..30], [31..40] and [41..44]" these are not consistent. 0-10 = 11, and  the others are each 10. [1..10] would make more sense

Comment: "I know we can split string but in this case it's a number, any idea?" in any language you can make a string from a digit so do that and split it. Then you are 2 loops away from making the string that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
v=453; d=${v:(-1)}; c=${v%$d}; for i in `seq 1 $c`; do echo "[$(( i * 10 -9))..$(( i * 10 ))]" ; done; echo "[$(( c * 10 + 1 ))..$v]"
```

Comment: this actually works, so i guess $d is which ever divider i can choose right?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This will work only with 10s as I "play" with the digits place. If you need line [1..7] [8..14] it can be done with minor adjustments.

Comment: Please be aware that the % in c=${v%$d} is not an arithmetic remainder, but removing of the last digit.